# What gets put down by a gem install?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

How can I know, prior to installing a gem, what files it will put down on my system? I understand that almost all files end up in my GEM PATH, as displayed in `gem env`. However, aren't there exceptions? When I do a `gem install bundler`, doesn't it put the `bundle` binary into `$GEM_HOME/bin/`?

Is there a manifest file I can take a look at before I install anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way:

1. Download the gem you want to inspect using `gem fetch GEM`. This places the gem in the local directory.
2. Run `gem specification ./localfile.gem` on the gem you just downloaded. This displays a YAML manifest.

All gems are simply tar archives, so you can also just unpack them.